Terraform │ Error: Variables not allowed | Random Required Provider
When I try to validate this Terraform config, I get an error:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.58.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "3.6.2"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-north-1"
}
provider "random" {}

resource "random_id" "rand" {
byte_length = 8
}

variable "random_num" {
  description = "random number for S3 Bucket"
  type        = string
  default     = random_id.rand.hex

}
output "balti" {
  value = var.random_num
}


Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on main.tf line 25, in variable "randoms":
│   25:   default     = random_id.rand.hex
│
│ Variables may not be used here.

I am expecting a random number from output.

Values that may vary (in this situation exported resource attributes) are indeed not allowed in variable declaration block default values. You can use a local and the coalesce function instead to preserve the variable and output capabilities:
variable "random_num" {
  description = "random number for S3 Bucket"
  type        = string
}

locals {
  random_num = coalesce(var.random_num, random_id.rand.hex)
}

output "balti" {
  value = local.random_num
}


SIMPLE SOLUTION
Remove this 'variable' block from the configuration:
variable "random_num" {
  description = "random number for S3 Bucket"
  type        = string
  default     = random_id.rand.hex
}

Then edit the 'output' block so that it looks like this:
output "balti" {
  value = random_id.rand.hex
}

If you remove this 'variable' block and edit the 'output' block so that it references random_id.rand.hex instead of the var.random_num variable, then terraform validate command should not throw an error.
EXPLANATION
Assigning a changing value (the random hexadecimal) as the default value of a variable is not possible. The default value of a variable should be constant.
Using a variable here is also unnecessary. The value of random_id.rand.hex is used directly in the output, so there is no need to create a variable for it.
